# is there any simple way to do this than what i did

Tags: python, string, list, methods, append

Let's create a function that turns text into pig latin: a simple text transformation that modifies each word moving the first character to the end and appending "ay" to the end. For example, python ends up as ythonpay.

```
 def pig_latin(text):
    list=[]
    string=""
    # Separate the text into words
    for word in text.split():
        list.append(word[1:]+word[0]+"ay")
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
    for n in list:
        string = string + n +" "
    return string.rstrip()

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def pig_latin(text):
    list = []
    for word in text.split():
        list.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")

    return " ".join(list)

print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun"))
```

Comment: thanku very much  i was searching for a simpler way to make the lists to string easier even though i studied join method but i never used

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension:

```
>>> pig_latin = lambda s: ' '.join([i[1:] + i[0] + 'ay' for i in s.split(' ')])

>>> pig_latin("hello how are you")
'ellohay owhay reaay ouyay'

>>> pig_latin("programming in python is fun")
'rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay'
```

Comment: its great but ii dont know how to do like this anyway thanks

Comment: @NELSONJOSEPH What is the problem in this?

Comment: a function to change format of the string thats all

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "hello how are you"
for word in text.split():
    latin = word[1:] + word[:1] + 'ay'
    print(latin)
```

result:

```
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
ellohay
owhay
reaay
ouyay
```

implement this in your function above

Answer (score 0):

**Question**
create a function that turns text into pig latin: a simple text transformation that modifies each word moving the first character to the end and appending "ay" to the end.

**Logic being used here**

We'll create an empyt list
Define a variable which contains text in the form of splitted string stored in a list

**Code**

```
def pig_latin(text):
      new_list = []
      a = text.split()
      for word in a:  #consider a variable to iterate in a
        word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"   
        new_list.append(word)
      return " ".join(new_list)
      
    
    print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
    print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
```

*Hope it helps :)*

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer, but with some extra intermediate variables.